# Equivalent characterization of local connectedness in the plane

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness, path-connected

The way that I imagine local connectedness in the plane is the following "theorem".

> **"Theorem"**: A set $E\subset\mathbb{C}$ is locally connected at a point $x\in E$ if, for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $y\in E$ with $|x-y|<\delta$, then there is a path in $E$ from $x$ to $y$ which is contained in the $\epsilon$-ball around $x$.

I am sure this is a naive way of thinking about it.  I am interested in finding an example which will cure me of this way of thinking.  That is, a set $E$ which is locally connected at some point $x\in E$, but that does not satisfy the property described in the "Theorem".

Comment: The Q is whether a locally connected subspace of the plane is locally pathwise-connected (path-connected). I know of subspaces of the plane that are connected but not path-connected. E.g $S=(\{0\}\times [-1,1])\cup \{(x, \sin 1/x): x\in (0,1)\}.$  But $S$ is not locally connected.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46748/is-every-locally-connected-subset-of-euclidean-space-rn-locally-path-connected

Comment: Yes if it is also compact which I think is the case you care about.